# What is the difference between different utf8mb4 binary collations?

Tags: mysql, collation, utf-8

What is the difference between `utf8mb4_0900_bin` vs `utf8mb4_bin` binary collations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are three differences as far as I can tell (according to their documentation):

1. Case-mappings (for `LOWER()` / `UPPER()` functions):

   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html#charset-unicode-sets-uca

   > The LOWER() and UPPER() functions perform case folding according to the collation of their argument.

   The difference between the two collations in this context is that the `_0900_` version, being based on a newer version of Unicode, quite likely has more mapping definitions (and possibly even some corrections).
2. Padding vs No Padding (of trailing spaces):

   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html#charset-unicode-sets-pad-attributes

   > The pad attribute for `utf8mb4_bin` is `PAD SPACE`, whereas for `utf8mb4_0900_bin` it is `NO PAD`. Consequently, operations involving `utf8mb4_0900_bin` do not add trailing spaces, and comparisons involving strings with trailing spaces may differ for the two collations

   Essentially, `utf8mb4_bin` ignores trailing spaces while `utf8mb4_0900_bin` does not ignore them. See the documentation (linked above) for an example.
3. Sorting (performance only, not the ordering):

   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-unicode-sets.html#charset-unicode-sets-collating-weights

   > - For `_bin` collations except `utf8mb4_0900_bin`, the weight is based on the code point, possibly with leading zero bytes added.
   > - For `utf8mb4_0900_bin`, the weight is the `utf8mb4` encoding bytes. The sort order is the same as for `utf8mb4_bin`, but much faster.

   Translating that into human, they are saying that for a code point such as U+FF9D, `utf8mb4_bin` will see the UTF-8 encoded byte sequence of **EF BE 9D** and convert that into **00 FF 9D**. But, `utf8mb4_0900_bin` will *not* convert it into the code point value. This is due to the UTF-8 byte sequence already being sequential, hence the ordering is the same as it for the code point values. So why bother with that extra conversion step?

Comment: wow, that you very much for the answer, especially for mentioning the `PAD SPACE` as prior 0900 strings like `c` and `c ` (notice the extra space) were equal